"How to leak a secret" Ring signature soundness proof
I'm a beginner and I'm reading the paper "How to leak a secret" by Rivest,Shamir and Tauman. In the paper they proved the soundness property of the ring signature, Could someone tell me if I'm understanding their proof correctly ?
The key idea is to reduce $B$ a
polynomial time algorithm to invert RSA encryption on random input $y$ WITH NON-TRIVAL PROBABILITY to
$A$ a polynomial time algorithm to forge a ring signature $sig(m)$ on any $m$. (ie. use $A$ to construct $B$)
Since it's unknown that $B$ exists, this implies it's also unknown that $A$ exists. Or equivalently,  forging ring signature is as least as hard as breaking RSA. This provides security to ring signature.
Consider the sequence of queries $A$ makes to $E$ or $E^{-1}$ (symmetric encryption), the authors (sound reasonable but they didn't explain) assumed that there's an $r$-subsequence of the queries that corresponds to the forged signature ie. can be rearranged into below picture (p.560) with hash $k = h(m)$ and $sig(m) = (P_1,...,P_r;v;x_1, ...,x_r)$.

Since $A$ cannot invert any $g_i$ (RSA encryption), we must have "a gap" occurring at some index $i$ (in above picture) ie. either of the below cases (note: CW means $E$ and CCW means $E^{-1}$)

$i$th $E$ queried CW and $(i+1)$th $E$ queried CCW

Both $E$ queried CW but the $i$th $E$ queried AFTER the $(i+1)$th $E$.

Both $E$ queried CCW but the $i$th $E$ queried BEFORE the $(i+1)$th $E$.


In all cases $B$ can "slip $y$ into the gap" by giving a RANDOM ANSWER (deceive $A$) to the later query which is based on his knowledge of the input and output of earlier query in such a way the XOR of the values across the gap is the desired $y$.
e.g. In case $2$, $A$ first asks for $E(w)$ then $E(v)$. $B$ is going to give a faithful answer for $E(w)$ but he'll give $\alpha$ for $E(v)$ satisfying $y\oplus \alpha = E(w)$.
This would force $A$ to produce $x_i = g_{i}^{-1}(y)$ in the ring signature $sig(m)$, thus $B$ successfully inverted RSA encryption on random $y$.
While $B$ doesn't know where the the gap (the $2$ $E$s) is, he can just randomly guess $2$ $E$s as the gap with probability $1/Q^2$ of guessing correctly where $Q$ is number of
queries $A$ asked on $E$ or $E^{-1}$. Since $Q$ is polynomial in input size the probability is non trivial. Clearly $B$ runs in polynomial time.

Hi C.C. Thanks for putting so much work in your question! I'd like to indicate that it isn't entirely clear to me what is part of the paper and what is part of your "understanding" of it. Maybe you can clear that up to make it easier for other users to possibly answer the question.

@MaartenBodewes Thanks, basically I extracted the most important ideas in their proof (2 page long, 561-563), rewrite it in my own word and gave some examples myself. I want to know if this's indeed their main idea.  btw when I searched the site I couldn't find any discussion on their proof so I also hope this could help others.
